# 2 block-level navs on same line and centered

Tags: css, html

I'm create a vertical dropdown navigation menu with folding submenus.

HTML:

```
<h2>Navigation dropdown with unfold effect</h2>
<ul class="navigation">
    <a class="main" href="#url">Menu 1</a>
    <li class="n1"><a href="#">item #1</a></li>
    <li class="n2"><a href="#">item #2</a></li>
    <li class="n3"><a href="#">item #3</a></li>
    <li class="n4"><a href="#">item #4</a></li>
    <li class="n5"><a href="#">item #5</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="navigation">
    <a class="main" href="#url">Menu 2</a>
    <li class="n1"><a href="#">item #1</a></li>
    <li class="n2"><a href="#">item #2</a></li>
    <li class="n3"><a href="#">item #3</a></li>
    <li class="n4"><a href="#">item #4</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```css
.navigation {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 250px; 
  height: 40px; 
  margin: 5px auto;
  background: #95C11F;
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 100;
}

.navigation, .navigation a.main {
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
}

.navigation:hover, .navigation:hover a.main {
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

.navigation a.main {
  display: block; 
  height: 40px;
  font: bold 15px/40px arial, sans-serif; 
  text-align: center; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: #FFF;  
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

.navigation:hover a.main {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
}

.navigation li { 
  width: 250px; 
  height: 40px;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  font: normal 12px/40px arial, sans-serif !important; 
  color: #999;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}

.navigation li:nth-child(even) { background: #F5F5F5; }
.navigation li:nth-child(odd) { background: #EFEFEF; }

.navigation li.n1 { 
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.8s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.8s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0.8s;
}
.navigation li.n2 {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.6s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.6s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0.6s;
}
.navigation li.n3 {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.4s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0.4s;
}
.navigation li.n4 { 
  -webkit-transition:0.2s linear 0.2s;
  -o-transition:0.2s linear 0.2s;
  transition:0.2s linear 0.2s;
}
.navigation li.n5 {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
}

.navigation:hover li {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  -webkit-transition:0.2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition:0.2s linear 0s;
  transition:0.2s linear 0s;
}
.navigation:hover .n2 {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.navigation:hover .n3 {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.4s;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
.navigation:hover .n4 {
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.6s;
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}
.navigation:hover .n5 {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.8s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.8s;
  transition-delay: 0.8s;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Q6WR/1/

Is there any way to float the second submenu to the end of the previous expanded menu?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your menu structure. Example here http://jsfiddle.net/2e5YQ/

```
.menu {
   list-style:none;}
.menu li {
    position:relative;}
.menu li:hover .drop-down {
    left: 0px;
    position:relative;
}
.drop-down {
    left: -9999px;
    position:absolute;
}

<ul class="menu">
<li>Menu 1  
    <ul class="drop-down">
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Menu 2
    <ul class="drop-down">
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

But this type of menu is not very usefull because when you move mouse down under drop-down trying click to second element of main men drop-down is closing and and second element of menu go up that is very uncomfortably.

Comment: is not very useful indeed but I don't want to lose the unfold effect.